# Compress-Archive error: PermissionDenied

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to compress a folder using Powershell v5.1, but some files are used by another process and PS can't force or ignore them.

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\folder" | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath "C:\file.zip"
```

Also tested with `-Force` and `-ErrorAction Ignore,Continue,SilentlyContinue`, but every time I get an error like this:

```
ZipArchiveHelper : The process cannot access the file 'C:\folder\filexyz' be cause it is being used by another process.
At C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive.psm1:69
6 char:30
+ ... sArchived = ZipArchiveHelper $subDirFiles.ToArray() $destinationPath  ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\folder\filexyz:String) [Write-Error], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CompressArchiveUnauthorizedAccessError,ZipArchiveHelper

New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Stream was not readable."
At C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive.psm1:80
7 char:38
+ ...     $srcStream = New-Object System.IO.BinaryReader $currentFileStream
+                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Comment: There is no error action `Ignore/Continue` (or `Ignore`). Did you try `SilentlyContinue`?

Comment: yes, I tested almost all of them

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\folder -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Compress-Archive -Destination D:\file.zip`

Comment: Also, you're getting access denied, not file in use. `CompressArchiveUnauthorizedAccessError` this implies you don't have access to `D:\ `

Comment: I fixed that example... I have full access everywhere -administrator

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: I have the same issue, anyone has the solution.

Comment: My folder was in a long path, after moving it to user home it worked. I assume it has to do with long paths.

Comment: You can find the PowerShell solution using `IO.Compression` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72607926/how-do-i-compress-files-using-powershell-that-are-over-2-gb)

Answer (score 3):

The exception: `Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Stream was not readable."` occurs when using multiple files with Compress-Archive and one or more are open.

You can check if the files are not locked before piping them to Compress-Archive.

```
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path $path
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$itemsToCompress = @()
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$itemsToNotCompress = @()

foreach ($item in $items){
    Try {
        # Checking File Mode and Access
        $FileStream = [System.IO.File]::Open($item.FullName,'Open','Read')
        if ($null -ne $FileStream){
            $FileStream.Close()
            $FileStream.Dispose()
            $itemsToCompress += $item
        }
    }
    Catch {
        $itemsToNotCompress += $item
    }
}

$itemsToCompress | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $archivefile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the $Error object. If it is populated after the compress call, then an error occurred and you can take appropriate action.

```
$error.clear()
Get-ChildItem "C:\folder" | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath "C:\file.zip"
if ($error[0] -ne $null) {
    # Take appropriate action here
}
```

See this thread for more information.
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2026265-checking-the-success-or-failure-of-compress-archive

Answer (score 0):

Since files that are used by another process can still be **read** I assume the problem is having insufficient privileges.

Try starting PowerShell as Administrator (Search for PowerShell -> Right click -> Run as Administrator).

Comment: I am administrator and fixed that example and I running all as administrator by default...